# python if statement syntax error. NameError: name is not defined

Tags: python

What am I typing wrong?
I get the following error:

[RUN OUTPUT]

```
    Please pick the number next
    to your mood:
    1) Happy
    2) Indifferent
    3) Sad
1,2, or 3?
2
:-|
would you like to choose again? y\n :
y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\scratch.py", line 35, in <module>
    main()
  File ".\scratch.py", line 5, in main
    again()
  File ".\scratch.py", line 8, in again
    yn = input('would you like to choose again? y\\n :\n')
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'y' is not defined
```

[/RUN OUTPUT]

[CODE]

```
    #!/usr/bin/python

def main():
    select()
    again()

def again():
    yn = input ('would you like to choose again? y\\n :\n')
    if yn == 'y':
        select()
    elif yn  == 'n':
        print('bye')
        quit()
    else:
        print('your selection doesn''t make sense, good by')
        quit()

def select():
    print(""" Please pick the number next
    to your mood:
    1) Happy
    2) Indifferent
    3) Sad""")
    choice = input ('1,2, or 3?\n')
    if choice == 1:
        print(':-)')
    elif choice == 2:
        print(':-|')
    elif choice == 3:
        print(':-(')
    else:
        print("you must be drunk")

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

[/code]

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
raw_input('would you like to choose again? y\\n :\n')
```

instead of

```
input ('would you like to choose again? y\\n :\n')
```